# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException when calling Create method on Facet

Tags: contact-facets

I have the following code to reference a custom facet.

```cs
var contact = Tracker.Current.Session.Contact;
IHistoryFacet history = contact.GetFacet<IHistoryFacet>("History");
IHistoryLocationElement historyLocation = history.Locations.Create();
```

It appears to fail on the last line with an error of:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.

I do not understand why.

This is my HistoryFacet.cs file:

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using System;

namespace MySite.Models.Facets
{
    [Serializable]
    public class HistoryFacet : Facet, IHistoryFacet
    {
        private const string FACET_NAME = "History";
        private const string COLLECTION_CHANGE = "Changes";
        private const string COLLECTION_LOCATION = "Locations";

        public HistoryFacet()
        {
            EnsureCollection<IHistoryChangeElement>(COLLECTION_CHANGE);
            EnsureCollection<IHistoryLocationElement>(COLLECTION_LOCATION);
        }

        public IElementCollection<IHistoryChangeElement> Changes
        {
            get
            {
                return GetCollection<IHistoryChangeElement>(FACET_NAME);
            }
        }

        public IElementCollection<IHistoryLocationElement> Locations
        {
            get
            {
                return GetCollection<IHistoryLocationElement>(FACET_NAME);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my HistoryLocationElement.cs file:

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace MySite.Models.Facets
{
    [Serializable]
    public class HistoryLocationElement : Element, IHistoryLocationElement
    {
        private const string FIELD_DATE = "Date";
        private const string FIELD_IP_ADDRESS = "IP Address";
        private const string FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_01 = "Street Address Line 1";
        private const string FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_02 = "Street Address Line 2";
        private const string FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_03 = "Street Address Line 3";
        private const string FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_04 = "Street Address Line 4";
        private const string FIELD_CITY = "City";
        private const string FIELD_METRO_CODE = "Metro Code";
        private const string FIELD_REGION = "Region";
        private const string FIELD_REGION_CODE = "Region Code";
        private const string FIELD_POSTAL_CODE = "Postal Code";
        private const string FIELD_COUNTRY = "Country";
        private const string FIELD_COUNTRY_CODE = "Country Code";
        private const string FIELD_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
        private const string FIELD_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
        private const string FIELD_ZENITH = "Zenith";
        private const string FIELD_TIMEZONE = "Timezone";

        public HistoryLocationElement()
        {
            EnsureAttribute<DateTime>(FIELD_DATE);
            EnsureAttribute<IPAddress>(FIELD_IP_ADDRESS);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_01);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_02);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_03);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_04);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_CITY);
            EnsureAttribute<int>(FIELD_METRO_CODE);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_REGION);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_REGION_CODE);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_POSTAL_CODE);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_COUNTRY);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_COUNTRY_CODE);
            EnsureAttribute<double>(FIELD_LONGITUDE);
            EnsureAttribute<double>(FIELD_LATITUDE);
            EnsureAttribute<double>(FIELD_ZENITH);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_TIMEZONE);
        }

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<DateTime>(FIELD_DATE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_DATE, value); }
        }
        public IPAddress IPAddress
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<IPAddress>(FIELD_IP_ADDRESS); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_IP_ADDRESS, value); }
        }
        public string StreetAddressLine01
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_01); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_01, value); }
        }
        public string StreetAddressLine02
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_02); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_02, value); }
        }
        public string StreetAddressLine03
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_03); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_03, value); }
        }
        public string StreetAddressLine04
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_04); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_04, value); }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_CITY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_CITY, value); }
        }
        public int MetroCode
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<int>(FIELD_METRO_CODE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_METRO_CODE, value); }
        }
        public string Region
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_REGION); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_REGION, value); }
        }
        public string RegionCode
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_REGION_CODE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_REGION_CODE, value); }
        }
        public string PostalCode
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_POSTAL_CODE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_POSTAL_CODE, value); }
        }
        public string Country
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_COUNTRY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_COUNTRY, value); }
        }
        public string CountryCode
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_COUNTRY_CODE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_COUNTRY_CODE, value); }
        }
        public double Longitude
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<double>(FIELD_LONGITUDE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_LONGITUDE, value); }
        }
        public double Latitude
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<double>(FIELD_LATITUDE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_LATITUDE, value); }
        }
        public double Zenith
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<double>(FIELD_ZENITH); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_ZENITH, value); }
        }
        public string Timezone
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_TIMEZONE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_TIMEZONE, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my IHistoryFacet.cs file:

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;

namespace MySite.Models.Facets
{
    public interface IHistoryFacet : IFacet
    {
        IElementCollection<IHistoryChangeElement> Changes { get; }
        IElementCollection<IHistoryLocationElement> Locations { get; }
    }
}
```

Here is my IHistoryLocationElement.cs file:

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace MySite.Models.Facets
{
    public interface IHistoryLocationElement : IElement
    {
        DateTime Date { get; set; }
        IPAddress IPAddress { get; set; }
        string StreetAddressLine01 { get; set; }
        string StreetAddressLine02 { get; set; }
        string StreetAddressLine03 { get; set; }
        string StreetAddressLine04 { get; set; }
        string City { get; set; }
        int MetroCode { get; set; }
        string Region { get; set; }
        string RegionCode { get; set; }
        string PostalCode { get; set; }
        string Country { get; set; }
        string CountryCode { get; set; }
        double Longitude { get; set; }
        double Latitude { get; set; }
        double Zenith { get; set; }
        string Timezone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what key it is referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your collection getters need to access the actual collections by using proper keys:

```cs
public IElementCollection<IHistoryChangeElement> Changes
{
    get
    {
        return GetCollection<IHistoryChangeElement>(COLLECTION_CHANGE);
    }
}

public IElementCollection<IHistoryLocationElement> Locations
{
    get
    {
        return GetCollection<IHistoryLocationElement>(COLLECTION_LOCATION);
    }
}
```

Note that I used `COLLECTION_CHANGE` and `COLLECTION_LOCATION` instead of `FACET_NAME`.

Those are the keys you used when you *ensured* these collections in the constructor:

```cs
EnsureCollection<IHistoryChangeElement>(COLLECTION_CHANGE);
EnsureCollection<IHistoryLocationElement>(COLLECTION_LOCATION);
```

So now you should use the same keys to access them.

The `KeyNotFoundException` is thrown because there are no collections registered in the facet with the key `FACET_NAME`.

Comment: Wow, it is so Monday.  I missed that mismatch.